# How do I start over my code after a command?

Tags: c#, console-application

I need to make 3 zones in a game I am making and I need to reset my code so you could move between the zones is there a command or a code that can do it?

It need to be done on one window just after you want to leave the zone

```
if (choice == 2)
{
    Console.WriteLine("you live");
}

Console.WriteLine("you left the temple and went towards the forest");
// the code starts over form the beginning
```

I want it to just restart the code after the end of a zone.

Comment: Sounds like you just need a loop.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using a *switch* case inside of a *while* loop but below I have added a possible solution with a simple *if* statement (or *else if*, if you prefer).

```
while (true) 
{
if (choice == 2) 
{
    Console.WriteLine("you live");
}
//Have a specific number for the user to input when they want to exit the program
if (choice == 3) 
{
    //break from the while loop
    break;
}
Console.WriteLine("you left the temple and went towards the forest");
// the code starts over form the beginning
}
```

Comment: This will print 'you live' and 'you left the temple...' many many times when the user chose 2.

Comment: @JessedeWit I think it is meant to be that way but I might be mistaken.

Comment: My point is you will have to update the choice at the top of the loop, to avoid an infinite loop.